# Вопрос по поводу системы координат (WGS84 >> МСК-77, и наоборот)

Tags: координаты, гост

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно произвести конвертацию из WGS84 в МСК-77 (*местная система координат для города Москвы*), и наоборот?

Можно получить №ГОСТа или готовую формулу?

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел такой Proj4 для МСК-77:

```
+proj=tmerc +ellps=bessel +towgs84=316.151,78.924,589.65,-1.57273,2.69209,2.34693,8.4507 +units=m +lon_0=37.5 +lat_0=55.66666666667 +k_0=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0
```

Надеюсь поможет. Если получилось что-то другое найти, то буду рад любой информации, так как сам сейчас маюсь с этими координатами.